# register page using array to save information?

Tags: javascript

I trying to create a html register form and save the user input in an empty array this code does not give error but how i can check if the data is been stored in my array. look really simple i do not if this is the right way to do it.and i am using separated file in my thml

```
   function colectedInf(){

    var name = document.getElementById("FN").value;
    var lastN = document.getElementById("LN").value;
    var phoneNum = document.getElementById("TN").value;
    var userName = document.getElementById("UN").value; 
    var passwrd = document.getElementById("PS").value;  

   var userInfo = [];   


   userInfo.push([name,lastN,phoneNum,userName,passwrd]);

   /*
 for (i = 0; i < userInfo.length i++){
    for (j = 0; i < userInfo.length; j++){

        userInfo[i][j].push([name,lastN,phoneNum,userName,passwrd]);
    }
    //matrix.push([name,lastN,phoneNum,userName,passwrd])
    }   
   */
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution is to push each element into the array separately. For example,

```
 userInfo.push(name);
 userInfo.push(lastN);
```

And so forth.

Comment: i would like to create a multidimensional array, may be i have to use an if statement. i try in a different file and it works but here i can not display the array, sometime gave an error that my function is not defined.